# "Unable to get exclusive lock" when upgrading from 12.04 to 12.10

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 12.10

I have tried the suggestions to find other package managers running, but there are none. I have tried rebooting. I consistently get the same error message. Any other suggestions?